# Question about covering spaces extending inverse.

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

If $p$ is a cover map how would I be able to show that $x\rightarrow p^{-1}(x)$ extends to a functor $p^{-1}$ originating from the Fundamental Group of $X$?

Comment: The proof is simplified if you use the relation between covering maps of $X$ and covering morphisms of $\pi_1(X)$ explained in the book "Topology and Groupoids". I leave it to you to look this up.

Answer (score 2):

To explain more about my comment, here is the definition of a **covering morphism** of groupoids  $q: H \to G$. First one defines the *star*  at $x \in Ob(H)$ as the set $St_H(x)$  of elements of $H$ which start at $x$.  We say $q$ is a covering morphism if each restriction of $q$ to  $St_H(x) \to St_G(qx)$ is a bijection. One then proves that if $p: X \to Y$ is a covering map of spaces then the induced morphism $q=\pi_1(p)$ of fundamental groupoids is a covering morphism. This gives the transition from topology to algebra, one aim of algebraic topology. In this algebraic setting you should find it easy to prove that an element $g: px \to py$ in $G$ induces a bijection of sets $q^{-1}(px) \to q^{-1}(py)$. See [Topology and Groupoids](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/topgpds.html), Chapter 10. The functoriality is also easy.